# My question was closed as a duplicate of a vaguely related question without good answers

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Best practices for sharing tiny snippets of code across projects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/193415/best-practices-for-sharing-tiny-snippets-of-code-across-projects) was closed 6 months after being posted. It was marked as a duplicate to [How to promote code reuse and documentation?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175066/how-to-promote-code-reuse-and-documentation)

I'm a heavy user of many stack exchange sites and I feel that this question should not be closed

- The questions are different, and require different answers. The only similarity is they ask about code reuse - a very broad topic. My question is quite specific.
- The old question hasn't got the same quality of answers, upvotes, attention, discussion.
- The old question hasn't got a single accepted or highly upvoted answer.
- **More importantly:** There are still possible answers and suggestions that could be posted as answers to my question that still have not been posted. I won't write them here but since asking the question I've come across of a number of other answers/solutions that would be valuable to anyone reading the question.
- Before being fully closed, I edited in and commented my case for not being closed. This was ignored.

I wouldn't usually bother to write about this in meta but the question I asked is something I have and will always come back to as an important problem to look at. Closing the question without much thought throttles the discussion and prohibits further contributions by either myself or other users.

Comment: would you prefer it to be closed as too broad? "How does a software team best go about reusing small bits of code between projects?" -> _There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format..._

Comment: That would make more sense than the duplicate accusation, but I still would object. I put effort into making the question as specific as I could. It's about sharing small bits of code too small to be worthy of its own library. Its answers are not broad and are very useful. What good does closing this question do, even in theory? As far as I can tell this is a perfect fit for this site and has generated good content.

Comment: If I'm remembering right, the edit should have put it in the review queue for re-open votes. It may take time to accumulate the requisite re-open votes. Having said that, I can see where it could be considered a duplicate as there isn't *that* much difference between the questions.

Comment: Couple of re-open votes there already @AnonJr

Comment: "duplicate" and "accusation" don't stick well together, you better reconsider this attitude. It has been long time tradition at SE to respect duplicates, ever since [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) "...some duplication is _desirable_. There’s often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question around..."

Comment: "Having one “perfect” form of a question that contains every possible answer to every slight variation of that question is a myth at best and actively harmful at worst." ... "What we want is on the order of 4 or 5 similar-but-not-quite-the-same duplicates to cover all possible search terms and common permutations of the question. It is also OK for these duplicates to have their own answers" doesn't this article support my point? What's happened here is two questions have been chucked into the same bucket and answers are now not allowed on the newer subtly different question.

Comment: if the dupe-closure is wrong, the question should be reopened or re-closed with a more appropriate reason. I only wanted to make sure that readers of your [prior comment](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6164/my-question-was-closed-as-a-duplicate-of-a-vaguely-related-question-without-good#comment16634_6164 "'duplicate accusation...'") don't make an error thinking that duplicate is something bad, something _accusatory_. I have at least 6 of my questions closed as duplicates and I feel good about all of them, and I know these are OK by SE standards